# 404 not found in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I migrate magento2 windows system to linux system with database. Home page of magento2 is working fine but other page is give error
404 not found. If I add index.php in frontend url then it's opening but without it not possible. 
   And also magento admin is also not opening even after adding index.php in url.

Comment: You should set RewriteBase in your .htaccess and make sure that your Linux server have mod_rewrite activated and proper options are set in Magento backend. But generally, it's server-side issue.

Comment: i tried everything as you told but my problem is not solved yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was in my Apache server configuration
the below procedure helped me solving this problem

For Ubuntu edit the file **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** (here we have an example of **/var/www**)

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and change it to;

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all).

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me also, before trying this i tried a lot of different stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Did you see AllowOverride All? This is a commonly overlooked step. Please see:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite