# Installing magento from command line errors

Tags: magento2, installation

I follow this guide.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

I tried to run web installation but it always got stucked so now i try this.

when i go to mysql as root

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

there are not any tables for magento.

So i run this command given in the link

```
magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

but mine cant run `magento` so i use `./magento`

```
root@vegan:/var/www/html/magento2/bin# ./magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'magento'@'localhost' (using password: YES)



  [InvalidArgumentException]   
  Parameter validation failed
```

and other green writings

> ```
> setup:install [--backend-frontname="..."] [--key="..."] [--session-save="..."] [--definition-format="..."] [--db-host="..."]
> ```
>
> [--db-name="..."] [--db-user="..."] [--db-engine="..."]
>   [--db-password="..."] [--db-prefix="..."] [--db-model="..."]
>   [--db-init-statements="..."] [-s|--skip-db-validation]
>   [--http-cache-hosts="..."] [--base-url="..."] [--language="..."]
>   [--timezone="..."] [--currency="..."] [--use-rewrites="..."]
>   [--use-secure="..."] [--base-url-secure="..."]
>   [--use-secure-admin="..."] [--admin-use-security-key="..."]
>   [--admin-user="..."] [--admin-password="..."] [--admin-email="..."]
>   [--admin-firstname="..."] [--admin-lastname="..."]
>   [--cleanup-database] [--sales-order-increment-prefix="..."]
>   [--use-sample-data] [--magento-init-params="..."]

it says in informaton

```
--db-user

User name of the Magento database instance owner.

Default is root.
```

so i use my mysql password and admin name for it. this time it works but another errors

```
root@vegan:/var/www/html/magento2/bin# ./magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magentodb --db-user=root --db-password= root --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --cleanup-database help



  [RuntimeException]   
  Too many arguments.
```

SO, i decrease parameters. but again same

```
root@vegan:/var/www/html/magento2/bin# ./magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magentodb --db-user=root --db-password= root 



  [RuntimeException]   
  Too many arguments.
```

i can see

http://localhost/magento2/setup/#/landing-install

page here. i think there are no errors. i can run also setup but it stuck at %66 %67. yesterday i completed this but it was not adding to shopping card, today i deleted all php 5.6 7.0 in my pc and reinstall all. But now, it cant install..

what can be reason? i downloaded magento from web and extracted to ww/html

directory is

```
/var/www/html/magento2/bin
```

even for this errors

```
root@vegan:/var/www/html/magento2/bin# ./magento setup:install admin-user="root"



  [RuntimeException]   
  Too many arguments.
```

By the way, i forgot to put.

i create user and db before

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE prestashopdb;
7- mysql> CREATE USER magento@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'magento';
8- mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on magentodb.* to magento@localhost;
9- mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
10- mysql> exit
11- sudo service apache2 restart
12- sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: i have got a different problem installing Magento 2.2 using command line. this is the error message: [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException] The "-?" option does not exist. this is the command line: > php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://dev.myshop.com/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=my_shop --db-user=1234567 --db-password=pwd123456 --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=my@email.com --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --admin-user=superadmin --admin-password=12345678asdf as you see, I don't use the -? anywhere in there.
an

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140880)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140880)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create database 1st from command line or PHPMyAdmin. After creating database, run below command to install using command line.

> php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \ --db-host=localhost --db-name=rock --db-user=root --db-password= \ --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \ --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \ --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1

Above command will install magento2 quickly than web interface.

Comment: Hello sir. i tried with web and it succeeded but now anther errors

Comment: What other errors you are seeing?

Comment: 404 for localho magento. fr localhost it workds

Comment: enable mod_rewrite module.

Comment: ,i already enabled caner@vegan:~$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96439/magento2-installation-admin-page-404-during-installation

Comment: i already modified conf file and also added magento conf but same. :(

Answer (score 4):

Try that it works.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://www.example.com/staging/"  --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento_staging" --db-user="magento_staging" --db-password="PASSWORD" --admin-firstname="Magento" --admin-lastname="User" --admin-email="example@example.com" --admin-user="MagentoAdmin" --admin-password="Magento@#123K" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the backslashes was the problem for me with this error: too many arguments expected arguments command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the database and a user for the database first.
Then include these in the install command.

It might be easier to use the web installation, at what point do you get stuck?

Comment: At &66 %67 . i will tell you now.
again %67 Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_BundleSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Installing data...

Comment: again Module 'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_BundleSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Installing data...

Answer (score 1):

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://foo.test" --db-host="127.0.0.1" --db-name="magento_db" --db-user="root" --db-password="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="test@test.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin-123" --language="en_GB" --currency="GBP" --timezone="Europe/London" --use-rewrites="1"
```

In the above command change --db-host="localhost" to **--db-host="127.0.0.1"**

Answer (score 0):

Having tried all the solutions here while installing magento v2.4.2 community version in my localhost I had to remove backslashes as well as double quotes and that is how it worked for me. My command was as follows :

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento/  --db-host=localhost --db-name=magentodb --db-user=magento --db-password=magento --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=Magento --admin-email=example@example.com --admin-user=MagentoAdmin --admin-password=Magento@123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes